# iText 5 header and footer

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

how I can add in my PDF page the **header** and the **footer**?
I wanna a table with 3 column in header and other table, 3 column in the footer.
My page could be A3 or A4, and landscape or portrait.

Can anyone help me? I can not found on internet good examples.

Thanks!

Tommaso

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a class MyPageEventListener that extends **PdfPageEventHelper**
2. Add a page event listener to the PdfWriter object
3. In the **onEndPage** method of MyPageEventListener class, put the code
   for header/footer

Example:

```
public class MyPageEventListener extends PdfPageEventHelper {
  . . .
  @Override
  public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
     //code skeleton to write page header
     PdfPTable tbl = new PdfPTable(3);
     tbl.addCell("1st cell");
     tbl.addCell("2nd cell");
     tbl.addCell("3rd cell");
     float x = document.leftMargin();
     float hei = getMyHeaderHeight(); //custom method that return header's height 
     //align bottom between page edge and page margin
     float y = document.top() + hei;

     //write the table
     tbl.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, x, y, writer.getDirectContent());
  }    
}
```

to register the listener simply do

```
writer.setPageEvent(new MyPageEventListener());
```

Comment: your code is very confusing, you are using undefined variables (like c_document or header) and have italian(?) comments, could you please clearify it?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is first generate the contents of your entire PDF in memory, then once all the pages have been created you need to open the in-memory PDF in the pdfStamper and iterate through all the pages adding in the header and footer objects are the correct coordinates.

If you do a quick google search of adding page numbers in itextPDF you will find a number of examples that you can quickly adapt for your needs.

The key is that it is done after you create the pdf, not before.