# How to add image to header in itext 5.2.1

Tags: java, pdf, itext

[image]
How to add image to header in itext 5.2.1?

As the picture shows, the logo should fill the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already posted a quite [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11117154/1065525) some days ago. In my answer to that question, I pointed to this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9175638/1065525). Instead of adding text to the header table as described there, you can add an Image.

Comment: Of course. Your answer gave me a very important guidance.But.I know very little about IText. The IText version update too fast. So that it is difficult to find the right material in Chinese website.  Thanks very much for you.

Comment: New versions of iText are mainly about bug fixes and new features, and don't affect basic stuff like headers and footers for example. If you can afford it, you would do yourself quite a favor by buying [iText in Action (2nd Edition)](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/). It's the most comprehensive documentation about iText. You can have access to all the examples from the book [here](http://itextpdf.com/book/examples.php), for free.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use it:

```
Image logo = Image.getInstance("/image.gif");
logo.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);
logo.scaleAbsoluteHeight(20);
logo.scaleAbsoluteWidth(20);
logo.scalePercent(100);
Chunk chunk = new Chunk(logo, 0, -45);
HeaderFooter header = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase(chunk), false);
header.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
header.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
document.setHeader(header);
```

of course object document is: Document document = new Document();

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But This version(IText 5.2.1) hava no object "HeaderFooter".What should I do?