# How to add footer image to pdf in itext 5.3.5

Tags: itext

I searched many links but didnt get a proper answer.
Please suggest how to add image as a footer to pdf using itext5.3.5

Comment: Did you have any luck with that?

Answer (score 1):

There are questions where the same issue was asked, for the header - [How to add image to header in itext 5.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203831/how-to-add-image-to-header-in-itext-5-2-1), [iText 5 header and footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115479/itext-5-header-and-footer/9175638#9175638) - and here is adding an text for the footer - [How to add footer image to pdf in itext 5.3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874683/how-to-add-footer-image-to-pdf-in-itext-5-3-5), but it can be easily changed to add an image.